# What tag type do I need to use, so my inputs on submit, doesn't trigger error output

Tags: php, html, database

This is the php sql code for inserting into database I'm attempting to add to. New to this still, so would like some clarification. As I know i have to add validation as well in the furture. But would like to get this fixed first.

```
<?php

    $camper_id=$_POST['camper_id'];
    $parent_id=$_POST['parent_id'];
    $first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_POST['last_name'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $pick_up_name=$_POST['pick_up_name'];
    $medications=$_POST['medications'];
    $allergies=$_POST['allergies'];
    $group_num=$_POST['group_num'];
    $med_hist=$_POST['med_hist'];

    //for adding campers
    if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `CAMPER` 
                    (`CAMPER_ID`, `PARENT_ID`, `FIRST_NAME`, 
                    `LAST_NAME`, `AGE`, `GROUP_NUM`, `PICK_UP_NAME`, 
                    `MEDICATIONS`, `ALLERGIES`, `MED_HIST`) 
        VALUES ($camper_id,$parent_id,$first_name,
                $last_name,$age,$pick_up_name,
                $medications,$allergies,$group_num,$med_hist)";

        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if (!$result)die('
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Please fill all boxes with a valid response.");
        </script>
        <?php');
        echo 'Counselor inserted.';
        }
?>
```

This is the table for data input input i created. Another page when I update another table I dont have the types in the tags for each input. Which I tried for this before I gave them types, and still got same error.

```
<div class="content">
    <h1>Profile</h1>

    <div id="box">
        <div class="box-top">Update your campers information</div>
            <div class="box-panel">

                <div class = "box-form">                               
                    <form method= "POST" action= "<?php echo $PHP_SELF?>">
                        <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Camper_Id:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="camper_id" value="<?php echo $camper_id ?>" placeholder="campers id number" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Parent_Id:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" parent_id" value="<?php echo $parent_id ?>" placeholder="parents id number" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>First_Name:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>" placeholder="John" ></td>
                        </tr> 
                        <tr>                                    
                            <td>Last_Name:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name ?>" placeholder="Smith" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Age:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="age" value="<?php echo $age ?>" placeholder="123 anywhere way"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Group_Num:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="group_num" value="<?php echo $group_num ?>" placeholder="0-16" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Pick_Up_Name:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="text" name="pick_up_name" value="<?php echo $pick_up_name ?>" placeholder="Steve/Janet Smith" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Medications:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="medications" value="<?php echo $medications ?>" placeholder="(0=yes,1=no)"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Allergies:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="allergies" value="<?php echo $allergies ?>" placeholder="(0=yes,1=no)" ></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Medical_History:</td>
                            <td align="center"><input type="number" name="med_hist" value="<?php echo $med_hist ?>" placeholder="(0=yes,1=no)" ></td>
                        </tr>       
                        </table>
```

The issue arises on when i click submit, it is saying please fill all boxes with valid responses. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I don't get this error.

Comment: One mistake: Your values are in a different order than your column names

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks, I saw that early and have fixed that part.

Comment: You have not described your issue very well.

Comment: sorry for that if you would like to delete the question, than go ahead. I plan on working on this more tonight before asking again. Sorry for not asking properly, new to database and php/html